# Terminal shows "active process" as "-zsh ▸ -zsh"

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, zsh

I have configured Terminal.app to show the "active process" in the tab title.

When I open a new Terminal tab, it shows the corresponding field as "-zsh ▸ -zsh" rather than just "zsh" by default:

[image]

My suspicion is that this is related to how this shell is launched by the Terminal. According to `ps aux`, it is launched as follows:

`login -pfl daniel /bin/bash -c exec -la zsh /bin/zsh`

My user account's shell is set to simply `/bin/zsh`.

A `bash` shell launched via "New Command -> `bash`" is shown as just "-bash" in the title.

Is there a way to tweak the command Terminal executes, such that it shows up as just "zsh" in the tab title?

Comment: Just a remark: it's surprising that login invokes user shells by executing bash first!